# Linking URL to a page loaded inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a webpage hosted in Firebase that loads content from another HTML page inside a div upon clicking a link using:

```
$('#div').load(url);
```

The problem is that this method does not change the URL for the page so it is uniquely identified. Is there a way to make it so that when running that command it changes the URL so that the user can bookmark the page, and when that page is loaded it recreates the page with the loaded HTML?

Comment: There's no built in way to do this. You can use `pushState` to change the URL, however it will be completely down to you to recognise the URL that's been loaded by a returning user and put the DOM in to the relevant state. That final part is by no means a trivial task.

Comment: You could perhaps use a query string parameter to identify the URL you are loading in the div. The user could then bookmark this URL with the query string. But you'd have to add some code to read the query string when the page loads, and then load the correct URL in the div based on its value. Similar to what @RoryMcCrossan suggested.

Comment: My Suggestion is to call this page with query-string(value which need to load in div). So once page loaded , Just read query string and pass that value in your code.

Comment: I found an example of a page that behaves similar to what I have in mind btw:
https://aceproject.org/ace-en/topics/vr/vra/vra03/vra03a

I can't tell how they do it tho, but as you click links it changes the url without refreshing the entire page, and when you go to the link it goes back to that same state.